# Observable interval value cannot be used for arithmetic operation

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to multiple interval emitted values by 10 to have result stream as: 10, 20, 30 ...
However in map method I cannot multiply it because compiler throws error.

```
const numbers$ = Observable.interval(1000);
numbers$.pipe(
    map((x) => 10 * x)
);
```

error on map line:

```
The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.
```

I also checked that x is type of 'number';

Where am I wrong?

/edit

from Inge Olaisen comment
I changed code to:
`map((x) => 10 + +x)` and it is working correctly

can I assume that it is compiler bug as it does not recognise x as number?

Answer (score 0):

const numbers$ = Observable.interval(1000);
numbers$.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)).subscribe((x) => 10 * x);

That said it is a bit weird that the compiler complains, but you could try:
const numbers$: Observable = Observable.interval(1000);

unsubscribe is a subject that calls .next() and .complete() in the ngOnDestroy() method.

map you use if you want to map the data from one type to another. Typically if you have data and you transform that into another observable, that in turn subscribes or use it in the html in some form or another.

If you just want to use the data you get, then you put it into a subscribe.

Comment: hey Inge, thank you for your response. I have tried to use `const numbers$: Observable<number> = Observable.interval(1000);` with same result. In my case I want to understand why this code is not working as expected

Comment: The problem is that the compiler doesn't see that you have a number on both places. If you add a + in front of the x, what does it say then?
Like so: (x) => 10* +x

Comment: Alright, that means that your compiler interpret the x as a string. I cannot tell you why though, it is supposed to be a number.

Answer (score 0):

From the [LearnRxJs-Docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/interval):

```js
//emit value in sequence every 1 second
const source = interval(1000);
//output: 0,1,2,3,4,5....
const subscribe = source.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Together with mapping the current value:

```js
//emit value in sequence every 1 second
const source = interval(1000);
//output: 0,1,2,3,4,5....
const subscribe = source
  .pipe(map(n => 10 * n))
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

I'd like to add that you should manage the disposal of the your observables, here's a [good article](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0) on disposing/unsubscribing from observables.

Comment: Why use .pipe(map  if you are only interested in the using the result in a variable?

Comment: @IngeOlaisen, in OP question post he's using map. Also, depending on usage you might want to do the all preprocessing before it gets to the sub.

Comment: That is true, but when just sending it to console log or a local variable, I don't see the point of using map.

Comment: @IngeOlaisen you're assuming that OP is only doing something trivial like logging to console. Maybe he abstracted what the final intent was for the interval to keep the question concise.

Comment: That is true, I made an assumption. Point is just to get the explanation out, which is why I asked why you did like you did.